# minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex for UICollectionViewCell is incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

The image above shows the center of 4 cells. As you can see minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex and minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex is not the same. I have set booth Cell and Line to be 1.

Here is my code for cell layout: Thank you

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

         //Get device resolution
    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

        let screenWidth = screenSize.width

        let size = CGSize(width: screenWidth/2 , height: 500 )
        return size
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1.0
    }
```

PS: The screenshot is from iPhone 6 simulator. For iPhone 6 plus the spacing seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it's called `minimumInteritemSpacing` not `interitemSpacing`. That means the spacing will not be less than 1.0, but it could exceed 1.0.

As for your case, you could try adjusting `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, returning a width equals `(screenWidth - 1.0) / 2` to make the interitemSpacing exactly 1.0.